# PHP String to Array with Regex return with delimiter

Tags: php, regex

Here is my string, nicely friendly error in a single string.

> The service code name can not be empty at line 1.
>
> The service code name can not be empty at line 2.
>
> The service code name can not be
>   empty at line 3.
>
> The service code name can not be empty at line 4.
>
> The
>   service code name can not be empty at line 5.
>
> The service code name
>   can not be empty at line 6.
>
> The service code name can not be empty at
>   line 7.
>
> The service code name can not be empty at line 8.
>
> The service code name can not be empty at line 36.

I can count the occurrences using this regex exspression: `'/line \d{1,}./'`

With following code.

```
$regexStr = '/line \d{1,}./';
$occurences = preg_match_all($regexStr, $str, $matches);
```

However I want to return the array with the delimiter.
For example:

```
- The service code name can not be empty at line 1.
- The service code name can not be empty at line 2.
- The service code name can not be empty at line 5.
```

I tried using

```
$result = preg_split($regexStr, $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Without any joy, this just returned the string without the delimiter.

Also, if you are a regex expert, could you tell me how to exclude the intro `,` if it is the start of the string - very helpful!

I think the way to do it is using the `preg_match_all()` with the `$output` configured on param 3 of the method. However, I think my `regex` is wrong that it doesn't include the proceeding bit?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You may use [`\w.+?line \d+\.`](https://regex101.com/r/cNcIQL/2) in `preg_match_all`

Comment: @anubhava you god, thank you! Much appreciated, worked a treat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `preg_match_all` with this regex:

```
/\w.+?line \d+\./
```

This regex starts matching from a word character and matches till 1+ digits followed by a dot.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cNcIQL/2/)

**Code:**

```
if (preg_match_all('/\w.+?line \d+\./', $str, $m))
    print_r($m[0]);
```

```
Array
(
    [0] => The service code name can not be empty at line 1.
    [1] => The service code name can not be empty at line 2.
    [2] => The service code name can not be empty at line 3.
    [3] => The service code name can not be empty at line 4.
    [4] => The service code name can not be empty at line 5.
    [5] => The service code name can not be empty at line 6.
    [6] => The service code name can not be empty at line 7.
    [7] => The service code name can not be empty at line 8.
    [8] => The service code name can not be empty at line 36.
)
```